# Select Only Specific Fields From an Optional Navigation Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities - `User` and `Plan`

```cs
class Plan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    ...
}

class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select a specific user and populate its `Plan` property, but only with specific fields (`Id` and `Name`).
I know it's supposed to be simple, I just need to write

```
db.Users
  .Select(u => new User()
  {
      Id = u.Id,
      Name = u.Name,
      PlanId = u.PlanId,
      Plan = new Plan()
      {
          Id = u.Plan.Id,
          Name = u.Plan.Name
      }
  })
  .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
```

The tricky part is that `Plan` is optional (not in the sense that PlanId can be null, but in the sense that PlanId can point to a Plan object that doesn't exist).

When `Plan` exists, everything works as expected, but when it doesn't, the `Plan` property is still populated, with an `Id` but with a null `Name`

Example:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "some name..",
    "PlanId": 9, // There is no Plan object with Id = 9
    "Plan": {
        "Id": 9,
        "Name": null
    }
}
```

What I expect, is for `Plan` to be null.
How can I achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a condition on populating the `Plan` field?

```
db.Users
.Select(u => new User()
{
    Id = u.Id,
    Name = u.Name,
    PlanId = u.PlanId,
    Plan = u.Plan.Name == null ? null : new Plan()
    {
        Id = u.Plan.Id,
        Name = u.Plan.Name
    }
})
.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
```

After the discussion in the comments another approach would be:

```
db.Users
.Select(u => new User()
{
    Id = u.Id,
    Name = u.Name,
    PlanId = u.PlanId,
    Plan = db.Plans.Find(u.PlanId)
})
.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
```

`Find` should return `null` if the `Plan` with `u.PlanId` is not found (in the current context or store)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea. `Name` is a nullable field in the `Plan` table, I don't want to assume it's not null.
I already tried doing what you've suggested but instead of `u.Plan.Name != null`, I tried `u.Plan != null`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Why are cant you use referential integrity with foreign keys? You could instead base the null check on a `not null` field of the `Plan` entity?

Comment: I agree that it would be a better approach, but I'm using Entity Framework to work with an existing database, I don't have control over its structure.

Comment: I tried running it. It throws an exception `ArgumentException: Method 'ConsoleApp1.Plan Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[ConsoleApp1.Plan]' cannot be called with instance of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ConsoleApp1.Plan]'`. I also tried doing `Plan = db.Plans.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == u.PlanId)`, It works but it does it by running two queries, instead of one with an outer join.

Comment: @user10962730 if you need it to be a single query I would suggest using `.FromSql(sql)` instead. Linq to SQL is not always perfect, but it is fast (to develop) and easy. (if using EFCore 3, you will need to use `FromSqlRaw`)

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupJoin like this

```
var userPlanPair = db.Users
  .GroupJoin(db.Plans, u => u.PlanId, p => p.Id, (user, plans) => new { user, plans })
  .SelectMany(pair => pair.plans.DefaultIfEmpty(), (pair, plan) => new { pair.user, plan = plan != null ? new Plan() { Id = plan.Id, Name = plan.Name } : null })
  .SingleOrDefault(pair => pair.user.Id == 1);
```

The combination of `GroupJoin`, `SelectMany` and `DefaultIfEmpty` translates to a left join in SQL form.

Inside the `resultSelector` of `SelectMany` you query the specific fields that you need from `Plan`.

To get the final result - A `User` object with a `Plan` property, you just select the user and plan from the pair.

```
var user = userPlanPair.user;
user.Plan = userPlanPair.plan;
```